# How can I pass and display values from dynamically created input fields via POST method?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

I have a form in my HTML page which contains input fields that are dynamically generated. I am able to successfully store the data entered into these fields in a MySQL database. However, my goal is to pass and display the data after the user clicks on the submit button. When I attempt to do this, I get the following error::

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\Invoice.php on line 112 Array
```

Here is the snippet of my HTML form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="invoice.php">
    <td><input type="text" class="price form-control text-end" name="price1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="discount form-control text-end" name="discount[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]"></td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP to get post values from the form

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // getting all values from the HTML form
    $price1 = $_POST['price1'];
    $discunt = $_POST['discunt'];
}

<table><tr><td>'.$_POST['price1'].'</td>
<td>'.$_POST['discunt'].'</td>
</tr></table>`
```

Comment: Well of course, `$_POST['price1']` and `$_POST['discunt']` are both arrays now (because you appended the `[]` at the end of the form field names, and you can not "concatenate" an array into a string.

Comment: (Btw., the English word you probably meant there, is spelled _discount_.)

Comment: @CBore then how can i display them ???? what chnage i have to do in code ?

Comment: You can either loop over those arrays and output each item individually, or you could use `implode` to get them all joined together into one string value.

Comment: @CBore can u send one small example if possible for u

Comment: For anyone who edit questions, make sure you're not removing actual info (like the PHP code in this case)

Comment: You need an example of how to use a loop?? https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

To print arrays, you can use a foreach loop like this:

```
// Loop through the price1 array and print each value
foreach ($_POST['price1'] as $price) {
    echo $price;
}

// Loop through the discount array and print each value
foreach ($_POST['discount'] as $discount) {
    echo $discount;
}
```

Or use a function like print_r() like this:

```
// Print the price1 array in a readable format
print_r($_POST['price1']);

// Print the discount array in a readable format
print_r($_POST['discount']);
```

Or use a function like implode() like this:

```
// Convert the price1 array to a string separated by commas
$price1_string = implode(',', $_POST['price1']);

// Convert the discount array to a string separated by commas
$discount_string = implode(',', $_POST['discount']);

// Print the strings
echo $price1_string;
echo $discount_string;
```